# getDates() doesn't work if date is from related model?

Tags: date, laravel-5

here is my query

```
$events = \App\Event::with('pics')->with('place')->with('terms')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(8)->get();
```

and I have in both models ( Event, Term ) method getDates:

```
Model Event

public function getDates()
    {
        return ['created_at','updated_at', 'published_at'];
    }
```

and

```
Model Term

public function getDates()
    {
         return ['created_at','updated_at', 'from', 'to'];
    }
```

Now the problem is in blade view.

```
{{ $event->created_at }}
```

returns Carbon object, but

```
{{ $event->terms()->min('from') }}
```

return string()

so I can use format() to format first date ( Carbon return ) , but when I try format second date I get this ;>

```
Call to a member function format() on a non-object
```

How to fix this without using clean php date function? :)

Comment: my temporary solution in view Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event->terms()->min('from'))->format('Y-m-d')